# how to find folder path by using url in phpfox?

Tags: phpfox

**Please help to find out the url in phpfox**

I am new in phpfox.
i have stuck in to find folder and file in phpfox. Actually it contain 
multiple files and folders. Please help to find out the file of given using url

http://www.desimitro.com/index.php?do=/pfoxmapi/event/events/when_upcoming/show_15/page_1/username_ashish243

Answer (score 0):

The module is "pfoxmapi" (so the path starts in /module/pfoxmapi/) but besides that the rest of the url could be a param to the "index" controller or a param to /module/pfoxmapi/event/index.class.php. My advise is to contact the developer of that module and ask for guidance.

Comment: Thanks alot.i would be helpful for me.

Comment: if this answers your question please consider marking it as the answer, you will find a check mark under the Up/Down vote images to the left.

Answer (score 0):

If the module already existed, then add module name after index.php?do=/{module name}.
eg: index.php?do=/poll. If ur creating a new module then 1st create a module in phpfox my admin and then try

Answer (score 0):

http://www.desimitro.com/index.php?do=/pfoxmapi/event/events/when_upcoming/show_15/page_1/username_ashish243

In this url "http://www.desimitro.com/index.php?do=" is the root path .
And "/pfoxmapi/" denote to the module pfoxmapi created in module folder.
"/event/" is the sub page in this module and rest of the parameters are the variables.